# Is it okay to interpret P values as a probability of falsely rejecting H0 when it is true?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Suppose a situation where NHST gives out $p=0.001$. Since there is a rare chance of observing the observed value when $H_0$ is true, I can reject $H_0$.

But the observed statistics still can be observed in a population. When it is observed in the population, my rejection is a mistake. Since the probability of observing the statistics when $H_0$ is true is 0.001, the **probability of mistakenly rejecting $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true is 0.001**. Since the type I error rate of 0.001 is less than the permitted error rate $\alpha$ (such as 0.05), we just reject the $H_0$.

The question is that:
When we reject $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true, isn't the **probability that this rejection is a mistake 100%**, not 0.001(=1%)?

Do the two probabilities describe different incidents? Or, is one of them wrong?

1. P(Mistakenly rejecting $H_0$|$H_0$ is True) = 0.001 =1%
2. P(Rejection of $H_0$ is a mistake|$H_0$ is True) = 1 = 100%

Comment: "*Since the probability of observing the statistics when 0 is true is 0.001, the probability of mistakenly rejecting 0 when 0 is true is 0.001.*" The latter does not follow from the former.

Comment: Also, I think you may be mixing up conditional and absolute probabilities.

Comment: Over the years, the site has aggregated numerous quality posts on p-values and their implications. You can check those.

Comment: @mkt Then, is the statement "type I error rate of 0.001 is less than the permitted error rate α  (such as 0.05), we just reject the H0" also wrong?

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods Thank you for your suggestion :)

Comment: Your question is a complicated version of a more familiar one: "after I flip a fair coin and observe a head, isn't the probability of heads 100%?"  One resolution of that question is to point out that the probability describes the process of flipping the coin, not the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good and relatively straightforward paper that explains in detail p-values and related misunderstandings:

> Gigerenzer, G., Krauss, S., & Vitouch, O. (2004). The null ritual: what you always wanted to know about significance testing but were too afraid to ask. The Sage Handbook of Quantitative Methodology for the Social Sciences. Thousand Oaks, CA: Sage, 391-408.

In a simple sentence, it explains *what a p-value actually is* (p. 393):

> A p-value is the probability of the observed data (or of more extreme data points), given that the null hypothesis H0 is true, defined in symbols as p(D|H0).

On the same page, the authors present 6 misconceptions of a p-value. Your case is the incorrect statement number 5:

> You know, if you decide to reject the null hypothesis, the probability that you are making the wrong decision.

This is a wrong statement because of the same reason as two other wrong statements mentioned by the authors. I report their explanation:

> Recall that a p-value is a probability of data, not of a hypothesis. Despite wishful thinking, p(D|H0) is not the same as p(H0|D), and a significance test does not and cannot provide a probability for a hypothesis. One cannot conclude from a p-value that a hypothesis has a probability of 1 (Statements 1 and 3) or that it has any other probability (Statements 2 and 4). Therefore, Statements 2 and 4 are false. The statistical toolbox, of course, contains tools that allow estimating probabilities of hypotheses, such as Bayesian statistics (see below). However, null hypothesis testing does not.

And more directly regarding your statement:

> The “probability that you are making the wrong decision” is again a probability of a hypothesis. This is because if one rejects the null hypothesis, the only possibility of making a wrong decision is if the null hypothesis is true. In other words, a closer look at Statement 5 reveals that it is about the probability that you will make the wrong decision, that is, that H0 is true. Thus, it makes essentially the same claim as Statement 2 does, and both are incorrect.